# How to POST a simple formdata using fetch API?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, post, fetch-api

I have a simple form like this one below:

```
{
    "code": "test1",
    "article": "door",
    "price": 12,
    "vat": null,
    "status": 1,
    "company_id": 10
}
```

So i need to post this form using fetch API upon clicking on Add button.
The only error i'm getting after pressing Add button in console.dev with error 420 is :

```
POST https://api.factarni.tn/article/create   420
```

This is my try so far:

```
const New = ({ inputs, title }) => {
  const handleClick = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    fetch("https://api.factarni.tn/article/create", {
      method: "POST",
      body: JSON.stringify({
        code: "test1",
        article: "door",
        price: 12,
        vat: null,
        status: 1,
        company_id: 30,
      }),
      headers: {
        Authorization:
          "Bearer eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6ImFkMWIxOWYwZjU4ZTJjOWE5Njc3M2M5MmNmODA0NDEwMTc5NzEzMjMiLCJ0eXAiOiJKV1QifQ.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.XoDs7DEYWQm9AwWFEbR7CtKpgvTh_zH8E5V1e8nUp5OwQT3hjKMUBFRCa7p_v-1TXAF5VoSDGTt0vZRgtPj6u7mIzagi0CPkuQYVyUkhHo2wBOV-IHbCRTqg-M4d6WDQvfSp1C0OzUnEg8eduUr7F7znuLnAUZQKBZ_Xp9ogj8aAZo-R8Na0HE5h0L9fIslD9UFBj2192EVebpb2DJir16beotXpd04d_qC1WCrN3WMsWdvgl2BRrTiG6SkqqwZH1hZzNkajNtIrhpYLnSOBoE3SsiIczvctqexynxmlle7gWaBN22t1M3sk3NHCkdfkSrXRi3PIBr71qw2QWltkyA",
      },
    }).then((response) => response.json());
  };

  return (
    <div className="New">
      <Sidebar />
      <div className="newContainer">
        <Navbar />
        <div className="top">
          <h1>{title}</h1>
        </div>
        <div className="bottom">
          <div className="right">
            <form>
              <div className="formInput"></div>
              {inputs.map((input) => (
                <div className="formInput" key={input.id}>
                  <label>{input.label} </label>
                  <input type={input.type} placeholder={input.placeholder} />
                </div>
              ))}
              <button onClick={handleClick}>Add</button>
            </form>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default New;
```

How to fix it?

Comment: Error quote: `420 Method Failure (Spring Framework) A deprecated response used by the Spring Framework when a method has failed.` What does your back end expect the format of your body to be? Check that first, since your body format might be incorrect.

Comment: @Shilly I tested my API by adding the same values above (the first ones) and it's been added successfully. Also, my backend is expecting a formdata as body.

Comment: @Ava I think you will need to dig deeper into your server logs to see what is going wrong on the backend. The message you are getting from the server is too vague. That said, you might try adding 'Content-Type': 'application/json' headers to your request, but that's really just a shot in the dark. How did you successfully send the values to the API, with Postman? I would examine the differences between what the server received when you did it that way verses what it received via Fetch.

Comment: i tested exactly the first block of code with postman, and it's been created successfully. I know it's very shady and maybe the issue is mostly related with backend. And i'm thinking about retrying with AXIOS instead of FETCH. What do you think (because i'm not allowed to check backend)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed my problem by adding missing `Content-Type` and `JSON.stringify`:

```
await fetch("https://api.factarni.tn/article/create", {
      method: "POST",
      body: JSON.stringify({
        code: `1`,
        article: `porte`,
        price: 12,
        vat: null,
        status: 1,
        company_id: 10,
      }),
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        Authorization:
          "eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImtpZC...
      },
    });
```